# Python Salary Program Using Conditionals

Tags: python-2.7

I get an error @ line 19, the Bonus function and I can't figure out why. I'll probably get an error for the other functions too. I've checked my spaces, my numbers vs. my strings, and my DOM. My first problem were about my globals and I fixed it from `global comrate` to `comrate = 0; . I've got debugging blindness. Thank you guys in advance!

```
def main():
#Welcome user and get sales number
    print("Welcome to the Bonus Qualification Calculator! Please honestly answer the following questions:")
    name = str(input("What is your name? "))
    sales = float(input("What is your sales total? "))
    jobtime = float(input("How many months have you been with the company? "))
    vacationtime = float(input("How many vacation days have you taken? "))
#Define Global Vars
    comrate = 0;
    compedsalary = 0;
    bonussalary = 0;
    finalsalary = 0;

#Begin calculations
    Bonus(sales, jobtime)
    vacation(vacationtime)
    print(str(name) + ", your salary based on the information you provided is " + str(format(finalsalary,'.2f'))

def Bonus(sales,jobtime):
    #Calcultate commission
    if sales < 10000:
        comrate = 0
    elif sales > 10000 and sales <= 1000000:
        comrate = .02
    elif sales >= 100001 and sales <= 500000:
        comrate = .15
        compedsalary = float(comrate * 2000)
        if jobtime > 3:
           bonussalary = float(compedsalary + 1000)
        else:
            print("You don't qualify for a bonus due to your limited time at the company.")
    elif sales >= 500001 and sales <= 1000000:
        comrate = .28
        compedsalary = float(comrate * 2000)
        if jobtime > 3:
           bonussalary = float(compedsalary + 5000)
        else:
            print("You don't qualify for a bonus due to your limited time at the company.")
    elif sales > 1000000:
        comrate = .35
        compedsalary = float(comrate * 2000)
        if jobtime > 3:
           bonussalary = float(compedsalary + 100000)
        elif jobtime > 60:
            bonussalary = float(compedsalary + 101000)
        else:
            print("You don't qualify for a bonus due to your limited time at the company.")
def vacation(finalsalary):
    if vacation > 3:
        finalsalary = float(bonussalary - 200)
    else:
        finalsalary = bonussalary
main()
```

Comment: from a quick scan i cant see any obvious errors, it could be worth checking for tabs vs spaces in your indentations

Comment: Thank you for reading! I did state that I checked them already in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're using full quotes where you should be using apostrophes. You're using contractions in your print statements, which confuses Python. Just put "do not" instead of "don't" in your print statements.